# Get all children from parent child JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, algorithm, search

I have parent-child JSON data and I want get all children (nested children) from selected parent.

For example, I have JSON data :

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "parent": 0,
  "name": "Parent"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "parent": 1,
  "name": "Child 1"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "parent": 2,
  "name": "Grand Child 1"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "parent": 2,
  "name": "Grand Child 2"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "parent": 1,
  "name": "Child 2"
}]
```

And I have function findAllChildren(1), where "1" is "parent" and then result of function should be :

```
[{
  "id": 2,
  "parent": 1,
  "name": "Child 1"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "parent": 2,
  "name": "Grand Child 1"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "parent": 2,
  "name": "Grand Child 2"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "parent": 1,
  "name": "Child 2"
}]
```

And in other case, if i call findAllChildren(2), result of the function should like below :

```
[{
  "id": 3,
  "parent": 2,
  "name": "Grand Child 1"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "parent": 2,
  "name": "Grand Child 2"
}]
```

What is the proper way to create function to solve that case? Thank you.

Comment: please add the wanted result. is the data is ordered? does you have more nested levels, than above? wht should happen, if you want to get `id = 1`?

Comment: already impoved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just iterate over the original data and look for items that has the specified id as parent_id. If found, do the same recursively with the element's id.

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/6ydog1tj/2/

```
function findAllChildren (id, results, depth) {
    for (d in data) {
        if (data[d].parent == id) {
            data[d].depth = depth
            results.push(data[d])
            findAllChildren(data[d].id, results, depth + 1)
        }
    }
}

var results = []
findAllChildren(1, results, 0)

$('body').append(results.map(function (element) { return Array(element.depth + 1).join(' -> ') + element.name + '<br>' }))

console.log(results)
```

prints out

```
Child 1
-> Grand Child 1
-> Grand Child 2
Child 2
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I want get data include grand child too.

Comment: Could you change your question with desired output for given input? In the question It fetches items with `parent=2`.

Comment: I get it now. Changed the answer and jsfiddle, check it out

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck on your project. Hey, maybe you could also structure the data in a nested way to make this much easier. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/eokf884p/1/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Maybe for another case, because I retrieve the data from RDBMS.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Good luck with your project then.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to iterate all data and build a tree like object with properties to start the search with all given `id`.

Then the object is walked and the children iterated for the result.

```js
function getDescendant(id) {
    var result = [];
    Array.isArray(object[id].children) && object[id].children.forEach(function iter(a) {
        result.push({ id: a.id, parent: a.parent, name: a.name });
        Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.forEach(iter);
    });
    return result;
}

var data = [{ id: 1, parent: 0, name: "Parent" }, { id: 2, parent: 1, name: "Child 1" }, { id: 3, parent: 2, name: "Grand Child 1" }, { id: 4, parent: 2, name: "Grand Child 2" }, { id: 5, parent: 1, name: "Child 2" }],
    object = function (data, root) {
        var o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            a.children = o[a.id] && o[a.id].children;
            o[a.id] = a;
            o[a.parent] = o[a.parent] || {};
            o[a.parent].children = o[a.parent].children || [];
            o[a.parent].children.push(a);
        });
        return o;
    }(data, 0);

console.log(getDescendant(1));
console.log(getDescendant(2));
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi @nina-scholz, i want get data include grand child. for example : if I pass parent=1 i should get data with id=2 include child of node with it child too.

Comment: Thank you @nina-scholz for your help, I get great solution from martin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` to remove items from an array that do not match a predicate condition.

`filter` will loop over an array and run a function for each iteration. it the return value is true the item will be in the returned array.

The `parentId` function passed into filter is *curried*. it will lock in the parent id you are searching for in the scope and return the function that filter will run.

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "parent": 0,
  "name": "Parent"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "parent": 1,
  "name": "Child 1"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "parent": 2,
  "name": "Grand Child 1"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "parent": 2,
  "name": "Grand Child 2"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "parent": 1,
  "name": "Child 2"
}]

function parentId(id) {
  return function(item) {
    return item.parent === id
  }
}

console.log(
  data.filter(parentId(2))
)
```

Comment: Hi @synthet1c, I want get data include grand-child too.

Comment: @Hidayat do you mean you want to structure it into a tree?

Comment: No. I want search child and grand-child (nested) from parent node.